# Append element then it auto hide in jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I append a new row to table using jQuery, an error occurs; it auto-hides the row Which I have just appended.

```
var str="...";
$("#list_product").find('tbody').append(str);
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: then what this variable for?? `str="..."; `

Comment: You cant append anyhting else than a `tr` in `tbody`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also append the necessary tags for the table:

```
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neezvrsh/).